# r format csv with random line breaks and export

Tags: r, csv

I have csv files that for some reason have random line breaks after some codes:

I can read this file fine in R but I was wondering if there was a way to create an output without the random line breaks?  Importing this file in other programs is creating issues where the 416 becomes a new line.

id,Abuse,AbuseHistoryOfAbuse,AbuseCurrentlyInAbusive,AbuseHistoryOfCPS,AbuseImminentRisk,AbuseInterventionCodes,Alcohol,AlcoholCurrentlyInTreatment,AlcoholSuspectUse,AlcoholAdmitsUse,AlcoholInterventionCodes,Asthma,AsthmaHistory,AsthmaInterventionCodes,BarriersToService,BarriersExperiencing,BarriersHistoryOf,BarriersToServiceInterventionCodes,BasicNeeds,BasicFood,BasicFoodLimitedAccess,BasicFoodNoWIC,BasicFoodNoDHS,BasicHousing,BasicHousingHasRegular,BasicHousingHomelessWith,BasicHousingHomelessWithout,BasicTransportation,BasicTransportationNoneLimited,BasicOther,BasicNeedsInterventionCodes,Breastfeeding,BreastfeedingPrenatal,BreastfeedingInterventionCodes,BreastHealth,BreastHealthInterventionCodes,Diabetes,DiabetesHistoryGestational,DiabetesHistoryDiabetes,DiabetesInterventionCodes,Drugs,DrugsType,DrugsUse,DrugsInterventionCodes,FamilyPlanning,FamilyPlanningNoPlans,FamilyPlanningInterventionCodes,Hypertension,HypertensionHistoryHypertension,HypertensionHistoryPreeclampsia,HypertensionInterventionCodes,Nutrition,NutritionInterventionCodes,ChronicDisease,ChronicDiseaseHistoryOther,ChronicDiseaseInterventionCodes,Periodontal,PeriodontalNoVisit,PeriodontalInterventionCodes,PersonalGoals,PersonalGoalsInterventionCodes,Smoking,SmokingUse,SmokingInterventionCodes,SocialSupport,SocialSupportInterventionCodes,STD,STDDiscloseSTD,STDDiscloseHIV,STDInterventionCodes,Stress,PrenatalEDSScore,PostnatalEDSScore,StressScore,StressAll,StressModerate,StressHistoryMentalHealth,StressHistoryBabyBlues,StressReportsStress,StressCurrentlyTreated,StressNotFollowing,StressEndorsesSuicidal,StressInterventionCodes,WomensHealth,WomensHealthInterventionCodes
0001,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,NA,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,411

416                                                                                                                                                                                                ,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,5F11

5T42

,TRUE,Not breastfeeding,NA,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,TRUE,2041,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA

I added a screenshot that helps show more:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your data in a reproducible format--it's a bit hard to totally understand what you're getting at . . .

Comment: I don't think the line breaks are "random", it just looks like some of your text fields have embedded new line characters. You can use something like `gsub()` to replace new lines with something else.

Comment: Can you explain more how to use gsub to delete the line breaks?

Comment: `data$column <- gsub("\n"," ", as.character(data$column))` If you have a column that contains line breaks, you can do something like this. (I used as.character just in case they were read in as a factor). With `dplyr` you could easily use `mutate_if` over all character/factor columns.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using dplyr, can you share how to do that for all character columns?

Comment: If you share it as an answer, I will accept it since the gsub method worked for the two columns I suspect were the issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, R does know how to skip through null lines when reading CSV files. This means that the resulting dataframe will contain no unexpected linebreaks, so if you just write it to CSV again, it will, likewise, have no random linebreaks:

```
temp <- read.csv('table_with_line_breaks.csv')
write.csv(temp, 'table_without_line_breaks.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still outputs a csv with the giant line breaks.

Comment: Is there a possibility that these are spaces, not line breaks? Have you tried
running this: 
`data$column <- gsub(' ', '', data$column)`

Comment: I ran this: data$column <- gsub("\n"," ", as.character(data$column)) as suggested above and it seemed to fix the issue.  But wanted a way to apply this over ideally all string columns.

Comment: In the picture you have attached, in the line that follows 416, there clearly seems to be a sequence of whitespaces. Are you positive you have accounted for this